# C# random if statement and label append

Tags: c#, winforms

So, on button press, it's supposed to generate a random number and do an if statement with regard to what number gets chosen, however when I try this, I always get the first option. Also, within the if statements, I'm trying to take the text from an existing label, and append it onto another label, however on the label it gets appended to, it keeps printing "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text:" in front of the text, not sure why.

```
Random random = new Random();

int index = random.Next(0, 1);
if (index == 0)
{
    TeamTenLabel.Text += TeamThreeLabel.ToString();
}
else if (index == 1)
{
    TeamTenLabel.Text += TeamFourLabel.ToString();
}
```

Comment: yep min is inclusive, max exclusive. Doesn't make sense to me but is how it is.

Comment: Plus you probably want `TeamFourLabel.Text` instead of `.ToString()`. A .ToString() usually gives the name of the object - which is what you see

Comment: This is a classic problem; coincidentally, I'll be starting a series in my blog on Thursday about this problem and many other problems with Random, and how we could improve the way we represent randomness in .NET.

Comment: Please don't write `if` conditions that *are always true*. Your intention is that `index` be either 0 or 1, so say : `if (index == 0) ... else ...` and not `if(index == 0) ... else if (index == 1) ...`  -- don't write what looks like a test that is always `true`.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thank you, that fixed the issue i was having

Comment: `TeamTenLabel.Text += random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? TeamThreeLabel.Text : TeamFourLabel.Text;`

Comment: @RufusL, are we playing golf? `TeamTenLabel.Text += (random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? TeamThreeLabel : TeamFourLabel).Text;` is even shorter, but I do not think it is more clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the random range, you need to +1 for MaxValue because it is exclusive.

To random from 0 to 100 you need to use random.Next(0, 101) instead of random.Next(0, 100)

> Parameters
>
> **minValue** Int32: The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
>
> **maxValue** Int32 The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8iBZ3i

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(0, 2);
if (index == 1)
{
    TeamTenLabel.Text += TeamThreeLabel.Text;
}
else //if (index == 0) //If there is only two options 1 or 0, the second if is unecessary
{
    TeamTenLabel.Text += TeamFourLabel.Text;
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you recommend that? Is there some reason why you have an if and then an elseif that tests a condition that must be true?  Does this technique introduce any bias into the computation?  Why are you writing code that is much more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: Thank you, while I'm sure there are simpler ways to go about it, this did solve my problem, thank you very much

Comment: @Varehen: **It is important to understand why this technique is a bad idea in general**.  Pseudorandom number generators often have weaknesses in the lower bits, and this technique *magnifies* those weaknesses.  If what you want is a random bit, **do not take the lowest bit of a random source**.  Ask the random source for a random bit!  The correct way to write this code is `random.Next(0, 2);`, **not** the technique shown here.

Comment: @IgorQuirino: I don't believe I've ever made the claim that I'm the only right person in the world. The claim that I'm making here is that this code is unnecessarily complicated and magnifies any weaknesses that are in the PRNG, and that therefore this is a poor solution. My recommendation is that you improve your solution.

Comment: @EricLippert, i'm sorry about my words and i understand what are you saying. i get my eyes into the books again and i solved my answer issues, its okay now, right?

Comment: @EricLippert, I understand what you're saying, and I'll be sure to check out your blog to get a more in-depth understanding of the concepts. However, I only needed a quick fix for a small program for now, and this did the job, thank you very much for your help though.

Comment: @EricLippert My answer is valid now? Thank you

Comment: I still would not say `else if (index == 0) { ... } ` because the check is redundant. Just `else { ... }` is fine. But yes, this now efficiently and clearly uses `Next` to generate a bit.

Comment: @EricLippert Now its perfect, i have commented the if and tell user to avoid this. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

An `int` is an integer, a random integer *between 0 and 1* is always 0, **the max value minus 1** (Next returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum, and with an integer, there is only one option: 0);

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me greatly to understand why this was happening.